# Using replaceWith to populate HTML tags

Tags: jquery

I know that

```
$('p.heading').replaceWith('Welcome');
```

will replace the entire `<p>` tag with the text 'Welcome'

How do I just replace the contents, so I end up with `<p class="heading">Welcome</p>` ?

Perhaps replaceWith is the wrong function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('p.heading').html('Welcome');
```

The `.html()` function replaces the *inner HTML* of the matched element with its argument (or returns the inner HTML of the matched element if it is called without an argument).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) methods for this:

```
$("p.heading").text("Welcome");
```